# Help tooltips and screen-readers

Tags: forms, input-fields, tooltips, screen-reader

I have an input form that contains help tooltips for many of the field labels (usually more meaningful than the example).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLJdRX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**What's the appropriate/standard way to make these tooltips screenreader accessible?**

Is it enough to simply embed the tooltip in the `(?)` element? Should the help text be copied to an `alt` attribute or something?

Comment: This seems like an implementation question rather than a User Experience question. Implementation questions like this would be more appropriate on [so].

Comment: @norabora I agree...though--at least with accessibility--I find that UX is often the only ones that either care or push for it in a lot of situations. It's good for UX folks to understand this level of implementation as it can have a direct effect on how it's visually designed as well.

Comment: There appears to be two elements to this question. One belongs on SO (as you point out @norabora), but I think there is an element of "how do I make a tooltip accessible?" that falls into the UX court.

Comment: @DA01 I've had the opposite experience. As a dev, I have to fight our UX team on colors, labels, and other basic a11y elements all the time. It's pretty frustrating.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Good point. If the impl question is removed, it would be a much more interesting UX question.

Comment: @norabora Which part is the implementation question? I put some rough html to better describe the situation but I'm not trying to get help with it. I just find that when screen readers are the UX topic, you can't help but talk about the markup. How would you suggest I improve the question?

Comment: @norabora that is a valid point. I think my experience has been more along the lines "very few people" push for this. Sometimes that very few are on the dev side, sometime on the UX side. I'd agree that both more UX folks as well as more Dev folks need to be more aware of accessibility in general.

Comment: @slicedtoad, I've removed the implementation portion of your question so that the full question won't be closed as off-topic.  If you think that portion might be a reasonable answer, feel free to re-post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey are we not to post *any* markup here in UX? I get the desire to push full implementation questions to SO, but at the same time, I don't think we should remove all references to markup in UX. UX suffers from a lack of markup knowledge as it is. I'd argue to put the code snippet back in.

Comment: @DA01 - I wouldn't say that markup is never appropriate here, it can very often be helpful or have direct relevance to the question. I was only pointing out pieces of the original question that *might* have caused it to be seen as "implementation".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that accessibility is more than just accommodating screen readers.

Tooltips can be troublesome in a lot of situations:

- screen readers (as mentioned)
- non-mouse access (keyboard, touch devices, etc.)
- dexterity challenges (the (?) icons are often very small)

In general, you will want to:

- make the target as large as possible
- make the tooltip text part of the `label` for the field or use `aria` attributes to make the proper logical connections
- ensure that they can be triggered via onfocus and touch events.

Personally, I always argue against tooltips for use in general forms. If the tooltip information is useful, put it directly on the screen. That's the most accessible way to handle it. If the information isn't useful enough to display directly on screen, then it's probably not useful information to begin with so you can just do away with it.

Comment: The users are going to be mostly small school librarians who are not known for their computer literacy. If they don't understand something when they first see it, they won't use the software. The idea is to eliminate field ambiguity while keeping everything clean.

Comment: @slicedtoad that, to me, says "Do not use tooltips!". If they are not computer literate, then you're going to likely find that they struggle with tooltips as well. In any user test I've seen where tooltips are part of the testing process, they usually fail on some level--typically as being 'invisible' to the user. Eliminate field ambiguity *in the `label`* whenever you can.

Comment: @DA01 okay, maybe I'll ask another question about how to best reduce field ambiguity.

Comment: @slicedtoad that'd be a good question!

Answer (score 2):

Including an `alt` attribute is the first step for supporting accessibility on the web.

WebAIM (Web Accessibility in Mind) has an article with several tips, [Designing for Screen Reader Compatibility](http://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/). Among the many tips is:

> Screen readers will read the alternative text of images, if alt text is present. JAWS precedes the alternative text with the word "graphic." If the image is a link, JAWS precedes the alternative text with "graphic link."

W3C has defined a standard called [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php), which further enhances accessibility on the web:

> WAI-ARIA, the Accessible Rich Internet Applications Suite, defines a way to make Web content and Web applications more accessible to people with disabilities.

You can find the 1.0 spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/

It goes into further detail on how to improve your markup to define roles for various regions within your site. From the spec's Abstract:

> Accessibility of web content requires semantic information about widgets, structures, and behaviors, in order to allow assistive technologies to convey appropriate information to persons with disabilities. This specification provides an ontology of roles, states, and properties that define accessible user interface elements and can be used to improve the accessibility and interoperability of web content and applications. These semantics are designed to allow an author to properly convey user interface behaviors and structural information to assistive technologies in document-level markup.

For example - you can associate a [label](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label) with a [textbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#textbox), and place both of those inside a [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#form) region. This provides accessibility software with a much better idea of your site's structure, and can communicate that to the user better.

Comment: and alt attribute is for images--not form elements.

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip example given by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#tooltip) in [this page](http://www.oaa-accessibility.org/examplep/tooltip1/) goes:

```
<div class="text">
    <label id="tp1-label" for="first">First Name:</label> 
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first" size="20" aria-labelledby="tp1-label" aria-describedby="tp1" aria-required="false" />
    <div id="tp1" class="tooltip" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="true">Your first name is a optional</div>
</div>
```

This [Bootstrap Accessibility plugin page](https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin/blob/master/README.md) further elaborates:

1. Add role of Tooltip to tooltip div.
2. Generate a random id, assign it to the tooltip div, and reference it from the Tooltip element with the ARIA attribute "aria-describedby".
3. Remove aria-describedby when the tooltip is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips may be visible when styles are disabled, so the first thing you want to do disable CSS in your browser and see if the tooltips are visible. One way to do this is with the Web Developer browser extension. Here is it for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm?hl=en-US) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/). You can tab to them and see if they appear. If they are not visible when styles are disabled, make sure that your tooltip can be accessed using the keyboard only. So tab over to it with your keyboard. Does it activate?  In addition to this, add a WAVE toolbar to your browser and run WAVE on your page. This will show you accessibility errors you may have missed. Here are links for [Wave for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wave-toolbar/) and [Wave for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wave-evaluation-tool/jbbplnpkjmmeebjpijfedlgcdilocofh?hl=en-US).